# Перевод чисел и timestamp-ов в строку с учетом нужного формата

Tags: python, openpyxl

Требуется написать функцию, которая представляет число или дату в нужный формат. Вопрос общественности заключается в том, что есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека, которая реализует требуемый функционал.

Параметр формат - это формат, который присутствует в соответствующем разделе Excel. Такую функцию написать могу, но хотелось бы воспользоваться какой-нибудь либой, решающей описанную проблему.

Самостоятельный поиск в интернете не привел к нужным ресурсам.

```
def convert_date_to_str(date: datetime, xl_format: str) -> str:
    """
    Возвращает дату как строку в соответствующем формате.
    :param date: datetime obj
    :param xl_format: xl_format (например: MM-HH-YY)
    :return: строку нужного формата
    """
    pass

def convert_number_to_str(number: int or float, xl_format: str) -> str:
    """
    Возвращает число в требуемом формате
    :param number: Число вещественное или целое
    :param xl_format: формат (#,##0.000, или рублевый или долларовый)
    :return: строковое представление числа
    """
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

> Вопрос общественности заключается в том, что есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека, которая реализует требуемый функционал.

Разумеется такая библиотека есть и называется она [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Пример из документации

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> # Using datetime.strptime()
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("21/11/06 16:30", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2006, 11, 21, 16, 30)
>>> # Formatting a datetime
>>> dt.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")
'Tuesday, 21. November 2006 04:30PM'
```

> Самостоятельный поиск в интернете не привел к нужным ресурсам.

Жаль, что он не привел вас к документации по языку.

Comment: Я оценил ваше остроумие )
@alex Может подскажете как быть с такими форматами: 
  -  [$-F800]dddd\,\ mmmm\ dd\,\ yyyy

Comment: ваш вопрос - "Требуется написать функцию, которая представляет число или дату в нужный формат." А вот какой именно это формат уточнить забыли. "Параметр формат - это формат, который присутствует в соответствующем разделе Excel." - ничего не говорит о самом формате. А вот ":param xl_format: xl_format (например: MM-HH-YY)" говорит. Как следствие вы меня сами запутали. А теперь еще и обиделись))